# Migrating THREE.js hexplanet demo r58 => r59

Tags: migration, three.js

I am trying to port the great [hexplanet demo](http://kawn.github.io/hexplanet/) to the latest THREE.js version. (I am not the author but unable to get in touch with him so far)
The demo was written on r53. Migrating it up to r58 was easy, but on r59 the following vertice/face error occurs:
[screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/e5sryo.png)

I have combed through the [migration info of THREE.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) and the [release notes for r59](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r59) but cannot make out what the cause of this could be. The only thing that looked possibly related to me was [a change in PolyhedronGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/84615fe345ff850e446f3306ef1b0a9ee7ef0db4).
But since I am not adept at 3d geometry anymore, I hope somebody can share some insight on this.

Project folder with progress so far: [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!EU4WCJpA!F9H011rFy_6JHgrpOO8kJkl78zcSGl8_6kOb7X6RaBw)

Comment: The custom subdivision code no longer works correctly. You are just going to have to debug this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else wants to use the demo on a later version, here's the problem and fix:

```
var angle = Math.acos(v1.dot(v2));
```

Sometimes results in NaN, when v1 equals v2.
Inserting the following made it work on all levels on subdivision again:

```
if (isNaN(angle)) angle = 0;
```

Comment: I expect a better fix would be to clamp the dot product: `var angle = Math.acos( THREE.Math.clamp( v1.dot( v2 ), - 1, 1 ) );`